# How can I add a custom video stream to Kodi

Tags: streaming-video, streaming

I want to add the live streams from the following page to Kodi. http://www.ann7.com/live-tv/

That page has a link to the url http://41.21.178.246:1935/live-ann7/ann7.smil/playlist.m3u8

I am able to stream video on my andriod phone by clicking that second list. Now I want to add this to Kodi (Openelec) so that I can watch it directly on my TV.

I downloaded the file and show it below, But opening ip with my video player on Ubuntu complains that it is not a valid stream

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=250000,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.5",RESOLUTION=480x270
chunklist-b250000.m3u8?wowzasessionid=1024288844
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=550000,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.5",RESOLUTION=640x360
chunklist-b550000.m3u8?wowzasessionid=1024288844
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1300000,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.5",RESOLUTION=1280x720
chunklist-b1300000.m3u8?wowzasessionid=1024288844
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your m3u8 file, all of the entries are *local files*. They're pointers to files that exist at the addresses:

- http://41.21.178.246:1935/live-ann7/ann7.smil/chunklist-b250000.m3u8
- http://41.21.178.246:1935/live-ann7/ann7.smil/chunklist-b550000.m3u8
- http://41.21.178.246:1935/live-ann7/ann7.smil/chunklist-b1300000.m3u8

You should just need to prefix each entry with the relevant URL:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=250000,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.5",RESOLUTION=480x270
http://41.21.178.246:1935/live-ann7/ann7.smil/chunklist-b250000.m3u8?wowzasessionid=1024288844
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=550000,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.5",RESOLUTION=640x360
http://41.21.178.246:1935/live-ann7/ann7.smil/chunklist-b550000.m3u8?wowzasessionid=1024288844
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1300000,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.5",RESOLUTION=1280x720
http://41.21.178.246:1935/live-ann7/ann7.smil/chunklist-b1300000.m3u8?wowzasessionid=1024288844
```

This opens for me in VLC. I *think* it should be fine for Kodi as well.

Comment: Thank you. I found those URLS too. I will try and and give you feedback.